# display the current label disappearing the previous

Tags: tkinter

I am trying a program,which will display label for the respective name entered in the Entry box.
Problem: It overlaps and displays the label,instead of disappearing the previous entry label.
Please help me to disappear the previous entry and display the label.
Coding:

```
import Tkinter as tki
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

         self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm,text="CLICK 1", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)
         self.entry = tki.Entry(self.txt_frm) 
         self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

     def retrieve_inpu(self):
        entr = self.entry.get()
        label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm,text=entr)
        label.grid(column=0,row=3)

root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [tkinter Display current label,deleting the previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654948/tkinter-display-current-label-deleting-the-previous)

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the label, and call `.destroy()` on it to get rid of it before you create the new Label.

Even better, you could just change the text if that is all the needs to happen. Try the following code in place of your own:

```
import Tkinter as tki
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root


         self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm,text="CLICK 1", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)
         self.entry = tki.Entry(self.txt_frm) 
         self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

         self.label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm)
         self.label.grid(column=0,row=3)

     def retrieve_inpu(self):
        entr = self.entry.get()
        self.label.config(text=entr)

root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: calling `grid_forget` does not "get rid of it", it only hides it from view. If you simply call `grid_forget` and then "recreate" the widget, you're creating a second, then a third, then a fourth... widget. Also, your answer is puzzling because you say the code needs to call `grid_forget`, but your code doesn't actually do that.

Comment: Do you actually read my answers when you shoot them down Bryan Oakley? I appreciate grid_forget doesnt get rid of the widget and I forgot to remove that bit, but my answer clearly says 'you could just change the text if that is all the needs to happen', which is what the code provided then does.

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought I was being unfair. I've seen several beginners make the same mistake about thinking grid_forget destroys widgets. I'll fix your answer to be a bit more accurate.