# tkinter Display current label,deleting the previous

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying a program,which will display label for the respective name entered in the Entry box.
Problem: It overlaps and displays the label,instead of disappearing the previous entry label.

My Coding:

```
import Tkinter as tki
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

         self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm,text="CLICK 1", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)
         self.entry = tki.Entry(self.txt_frm) 
         self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

     def retrieve_inpu(self):
        ent = self.entry.get()
        label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm,text=ent)
        label.grid(column=0,row=3)

root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Please help me to disappear the previous entry and display the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new label every time the button is pressed, just change the text of the label. I have edited your code to demonstrate:

```
import Tkinter as tki
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

         self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm,text="CLICK 1", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)
         self.entry = tki.Entry(self.txt_frm)
         self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

         #create label in init
         self.label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm)
         self.label.grid(column=0,row=3)

     def retrieve_inpu(self):
        ent = self.entry.get()

        #treat label properties as a dict for tkinter
        #assign a new text value
        self.label['text'] = ent


root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Of course, if you prefer to create a new label every time, destroy the old one first. This is a different modification of the same code.

```
import Tkinter as tki
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

         self.txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         self.txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         button3 = tki.Button(self.txt_frm,text="CLICK 1", command = self.retrieve_inpu)
         button3.grid(column=0,row=2)
         self.entry = tki.Entry(self.txt_frm)
         self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0)

         #place holder for label variable
         self.label = None

     def retrieve_inpu(self):
        ent = self.entry.get()

        #destroy the widget if it has been created
        #you will have a bunch of orphans if you don't
        if self.label:
            self.label.destroy()

        self.label = tki.Label(self.txt_frm,text=ent)
        self.label.grid(column=0,row=3)

root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was glad to help. On a side note, if you put your button and your entry on the same row the layout will be a little better. and a little padding ('padx', 'pady') so it is not so cramped when it is all on the same line.